# I want to publish a list that can contain any kind of data type

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to publish a list of tuples or any other data type, Are there any message types that fulfill this in ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399958/i-want-to-publish-a-list-that-can-contain-any-kind-of-data-type/) by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2022-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I want to publish a list of tuples or any other data type, Are there any message types that fulfill this in ROS?

No, there isn't.

Or at least, not if you'd like those fields to actually have a *type*.

Message fields inherently [have a type](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Fields), such as `int8` or `bool` or `float64`.

There is no support for variant types, or untyped fields.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2